# Problem capturing signature on BlackBerry Storm

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

Details: I'm working on a BlackBerry app, and one of the features is signature capture.  For that I am using the sample code given [here](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/832062/How_To_-_Capture_Signature_on_the_BlackBerry_Storm.html?nodeid=1487548&vernum=0).

I am facing one small problem.

My application's screen consists of a header, 2 labels and `SignatureField` in a `VerticalManager`.

```
message.getMovePoints(1, xPoints, yPoints, null);
```

is giving absolute points (relative to screen)

and

```
_graphics.drawPathOutline(xPoints,yPoints, null, null, false);
```

is drawing a path relative to field because of that touch and drawing is not in sync.

My question: is there any way to get relative points from 
`message.getMovePoints(1, xPoints, yPoints, null)`?  or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put a few functions together that translates the coordinates to the Fields offsets:

```
int YourClass#translateToFieldX(Field theField, int x);
int YourClass#translateToFieldY(Field theField, int y);
```

Or you could make a function that takes the entire array and returns a new array of translated  points.  That's up to you.

The functions that you'll be interested in for the implementation of these functions are:

```
Field#getLeft() and Field#getContentLeft()
Field#getTop() and Field#getContentTop()
```

Hope this helps.